# How to switch on InterpolationOrder in only one axis in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

How to control the dirction of  `InterpolationOrder`  in this code, I would like it to be `1` along `y` and `0` along `x`

```
ListDensityPlot[
 Flatten[ParallelTable[{i/2, j, i j}, {i, 2, 10, 2}, {j, 0, 1.7, 
    0.08}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> {0, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Blue}, #] &), PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: maybe `iF = Interpolation[
  Flatten[ParallelTable[{i/2, j, i j}, {i, 2, 10, 2}, {j, 0, 1.7,  0.08}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> {0, 1}]; DensityPlot[ iF[x, y], {x, 1, 10}, {y, 0, 1.7},  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Blue}, #] &), PlotPoints -> 50]`?

Comment: Thanks@kglr, How can I keep the ticks of the x-axis as in the original plot? the tick should be at the center of the subdivision

Comment: change `{x, 1, 10}` to `{x, 1, 5}` in `DensityPlot[...]`?

Comment: I did, but does not give the desired one as in the original plot

Comment: how about using `iF = Interpolation[ Flatten[ParallelTable[{i/2 + 1/2, j, i j}, {i, 0, 10, 2}, {j, 0,  1.7, 0.08}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> {0, 1}];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iF = Interpolation[Flatten[ParallelTable[{i/2 + 1/2, j, i j}, 
      {i, 0, 10, 2}, {j, 0, 1.7, 0.08}], 1], InterpolationOrder -> {0, 1}]; 

DensityPlot[iF[x, y], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 0, 1.7}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Blue}, #] &), PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]